# What is the current instantiation?

Tags: c++

I was looking at the reference for dependent names, and I came across current instantiations. However, I am having extreme difficulty understanding the wording of it. Here is the link in question:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#Current_instantiation

It states that names can be deduced to refer to the current instantiation, but it never actually defines what can and cannot be the current instantiation, rather just shows examples, and tells you what can refer to it.

Could anyone explain what qualifies as being the current instantiation?

Comment: Do you have any code where this particular nuance might be relevant? This seems to pertain to templates that reference other instantiations of the same template with different arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informally speaking, the phrases "the current instantiation" and "member of the current instantiation" are defined to set up a rule that within the scope of a class template, names of that class and its members are for most syntactic requirements treated like non-dependent names.  This makes writing class templates less tedious, requiring fewer `typename` and `template` keywords, explicit `this->` member access expressions, etc. in some cases.

That cppreference page does define what can and cannot be the current instantiation, in the four bullet points under "Only the following names can refer to the current instantiation".  (Though maybe the "only" isn't the best wording.)  This list closely parallels the formal definition in the Standard, found at [[temp.dep.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.type#1).

Note that even though the Standard and cppreference.com talk about "*the* current instantiation", more than one class type can qualify as the current instantiation at a single point within the code.  For example, if we have

```
template <typename X>
class A {
    class B {
        template <typename Y>
        class C {
            // Point #1
            void f();
        };
    };
};

template <typename X> template <typename Y>
void A<X>::B::C<Y>::f() {
    // Point #2
}
```

At both Point #1 and Point #2 above, the names `A`, `B`, and `C` are all the current instantiation.  So are `A<X>`, `A<X>::B::C<Y>`, `A::B`, etc.

Only a class type can be the current instantiation, and that class type will always be either a specialization of a class template or a nested class within a specialization of a class template.

Note the rules for naming the current instantiation are in terms of the exact syntax used and in the context of a template definition, without consideration for any particular instantiation of that template or the identity of the types involved.  That is, we can determine from the example above that at certain points, `A<X>::B` names the current instantiation and `typename A<std::decay_t<X>>::B` does not.  And even if we later instantiate `A<int>`, even though for that specialization it's true that `A<X>::B` and `typename A<std::decay_t<X>>::B` are the same type `A<int>::B`, that doesn't change the fact that anything in the template spelled `typename A<std::decay_t<X>>::B` is still a member of an unknown specialization, not a member of the current specialization.