# Is it a defect when the base class is a dependent type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider a example in the standard

[Example](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep#type-4)

```cpp
template<class T> struct A {
  typedef int M;
  struct B {
    typedef void M;
    struct C;
  };
};

template<class T> struct A<T>::B::C : A<T> {
  M m;                          // OK, A<T>​::​M
};
```

The comment says `M` refer to `A<T>::M`, I doubt with this, because of these rules:

[temp.dep#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep#3)

> In the definition of a class or class template, the scope of a dependent base class is not examined during **unqualified name lookup** either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

That means a name in the scope of dependent base class is never be considered during unqualified name lookup.

Name `M` is an unqualified name. Hence `M` declared in `A<T>` is not considered.

Then according to the rule for unqualified name lookup, that is:

[basic.lookup.unqual#8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.unqual#8)

> For the members of a class X, a name used in a member function body, in a default argument, in a noexcept-specifier, in the brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member, or in the definition of a class member outside of the definition of X, following the member's declarator-id32, shall be declared in one of the following ways:
>
> > - if X is a nested class of class Y, shall be a member of Y, or shall be a member of a base class of Y (this lookup applies in turn to Y's enclosing classes, starting with the innermost enclosing class)

Since `C` is a nested class of `B`, Hence I think lookup shall be began at `B`, then `A`, due to there's a name `M` in the scope of `B`, hence the lookup shall be stoped.

> In all the cases listed in [basic.lookup.unqual], the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup **ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name**. If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.

So, according to these rules, the name `M` within `A<T>::B::C` shall refer to `B::M`.

The [outcome](https://godbolt.org/z/n-5ekP) is here.

GCC agreed what the standard said, however `clang` reported an error and denoted that the type `M` is `void`. The outcome of `clang` consistent with my analysis. According to these reasons, I agree `clang` is right.
So, I wonder is it a defect? Or what something I misunderstand ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618403/what-is-the-current-instantiation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [C++ Defect Report Support in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html), currently (2020-07-06) Clang does not implement the resolution of [CWG591](https://wg21.link/cwg591), where the paragraph with the definition of *dependent base class* and the Example you cite in the question was added.

Comment: Oh, I miss the definition of  dependent base class.